# Unhashable type : 'list' error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already checked some question-answers related to **Unhashable type : 'list'** in stackoverflow, but none of them helped me. Here is my partial code:

```
keyvalue = {};
input_list_new = input_list;

for file in os.listdir('Directory/'):
    pathname = os.path.join('Directory/', file)
    dict_table = []; # creates blank 2d array
    with open(pathname) as dict_file:
        for line in dict_file:
            dict_table.append(line.strip().split("\t"))
    dict_list = [];
    for i in list(range(0, len(dict_table))):
        dict_list.append(dict_table[i][0])
    matched = list(set(dict_list) & set(input_list)) 
    for i in list(range(0, len(matched))):
        temp = [dict_table[0][0]] + dict_table[(dict_list.index(matched[i]))]

        input_list_new.insert((input_list_new.index(matched[i])), temp)

        dict = {matched[i] : temp}
        keyvalue.update(dict)
```

where `dict_table` is a list of lists, `dict_list` is just a list & `keyvalue` is a python dictionary. The entire code runs well when ever I comment the line `input_list_new.insert((input_list_new.index(matched[i])), temp)`, but without that line being commented, it shows `Unhashable type : 'list'` error.

Comment: I'd suggest eliminating the semi-colons; this is Python :)

Comment: can you show the error exactly ? in which line is the error coming ?>

Comment: Please paste the full Traceback of the error into your question; put it in a code block to preserve formatting. BTW, it's a bad idea to use `dict` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `dict` type, which can lead to mysterious bugs if you attempt to create a dictionary using `dict()`. That's not a problem for the partial code you've posted, but it may affect subsequent code in that function / module.

Comment: Use pieces from the problem line to see which of those is causing the problem.  That is, put `matched[i]` on its on line, put `input...()` on its own, etc

Comment: Some place or other you are using a list as a key to a dictionary or set, e.g. ` set([[1,2],3])` produces this error.  So does `{}[[1,2]]`.

Comment: Hello Kaustav, I'm giving the output:                                                                                        `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-30-8b66f18f9113>", line 28, in <module>
    matched = list(set(dict_list) & set(input_list))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Here `line 28` means `for line in dict_file:`

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not correspond to the line

```
input_list_new.insert((input_list_new.index(matched[i])), temp)
```

being commented out. If anything, the culprit is the line

```
dict = {matched[i] : temp}
```

The problem should be that you are trying to use a **list** as your **dictionary** key. Here is the problem in a simple reproducible way:

```
{[]: 5}  # throws TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The reason it fails, is because a **dictionary** is also be called a **hashmap** (in other languages). The key must be hashable, and in Python trying to use a **list** as the key throws your error becauses lists are not hashable (see "hashable" entry [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html)).

Avoid using a list as your dictionary key will fix the problem.

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for your suggestion. But I'm not using a list as a key of the python dictionary, `matched[i]` is just a string.

Comment: is it possible that a list is somehow inserted into `matched`? Can you do `print(matched[i])` each time before `dict = {matched[i] : temp}` and see the last value before it crashes? Also it would be very useful to see what line number the error happens on.

Comment: A dictionary is not necessarily a hashmap so the terms aren't synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess .... You mentioned that the error is with the line `matched = list(set(dict_list) & set(input_list))` .. That is probably because in either `input_list` or `dict_list`, you have a list within a list .... the items in a set need to hashable, and hence immutable .. for example you cannot do `set([1,5,6,[1,3]])` ... that will give the unhashable type list error ... but you can do `set([1,5,6,(1,3)])` because a tuple is immutable and hashable